# How to raise a click event when selecting a tab in TTabSet via TabIndex?

Tags: vbscript, automation, tabindex, automated-tests, testcomplete

I have a TestComplete test that selects a tab in a `TTabSet` using the `TabIndex` property:

```
Tab.TabIndex = 1
```

That works great. However, I am noticing that some of the objects on that tab require the click event to occur to be enabled. That said, how can I select the tab item via the `TabIndex` with some sort of a click event involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of assigning a value to `TabIndex`, you can call `TTabSet`'s [`ItemRect`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Tabs.TTabSet.ItemRect) method to get the coordinates of a tab by its index, and then pass these coordinates to TestComplete's `Click` method. Here's an example:

```
Sub Main
  Set tabSet = Sys.Process("Project1").VCLObject("Form1").VCLObject("TabSet1")

  For i = 0 To tabSet.Tabs.Count
    ClickTab tabSet, i
    Delay 1000
  Next
End Sub

Sub ClickTab(TTabSet, ItemIndex)
  Dim rect, x, y
  Set rect = TTabSet.ItemRect(ItemIndex)
  x = (rect.Left + rect.Right)  / 2
  y = (rect.Top  + rect.Bottom) / 2

  TTabSet.Click x, y 
End Sub
```

However, this approach requires that:

- Your tested application is built with debug information (this makes public members, including `ItemRect`, available to TestComplete).
- The application code contains the `ItemRect` method call (otherwise this method will be left out of the EXE by Delphi's smart linker, so it will be unavailable to TestComplete).

Also, if your tab control has more tabs than are displayed (that is, `Tabs.Count` > `VisibleTabs`), you'll need to scroll it to make the needed tab visible first. You can do this, for example, using the [`FirstIndex`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Tabs.TTabSet.FirstIndex) property:

```
Sub ClickTab(TTabSet, ItemIndex)
  If ItemIndex >= TTabSet.FirstIndex + TTabSet.VisibleTabs Then
    TTabSet.FirstIndex = ItemIndex
  End If

  Dim index, rect, x, y
  index = ItemIndex - TTabSet.FirstIndex

  Set rect = TTabSet.ItemRect(index)
  x = (rect.Left + rect.Right)  \ 2
  y = (rect.Top  + rect.Bottom) \ 2

  TTabSet.Click x, y 
End Sub
```